# QML hack/fiddle to get something to trigger change in state

Tags: qml

I'm pretty new to working with QML, we have some buttons that are enabled and disabled according to other content on the page.  When the other controls are updated there is some JavaScript functions that can be used to determine if the buttons should be enabled or disabled.  Originally these functions were assigned to the qml buttons enabled properties, however it seems this isn't enough and a fiddle to make it work is to have a property defined in QML (integer) which is incremented and this is then used by the enabled property to flag an update, this works but seems very hacky and not the correct way to do it.

```
    Item {    
        id: root
        property int qmlChangeFiddle: 0
        ...
        Button {
            id: prevImageButton
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 24
            anchors.top: capturedAreaRect.top
            enabled: (root.qmlChangeFiddle > 0)
            height: cameraButtonBar.height
            width: cameraButtonBar.width * 0.125
            icon: "leftarrow.svg"
            visible: capturedFrame.visible && (imageCaptureModel.capturableSelected.length > 1)
            ....
        }
    }
```

Incrementing "root.qmllChangeFiddle" will cause it to change and the button enabled, before I was calling a JavaScript routine which returns true or false but this didn't work.

Original qml which doesn't work:

```
    Item {    
        id: root
        ...
        Button {
            id: prevImageButton
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 24
            anchors.top: capturedAreaRect.top
            enabled: images.moreThanOne()
            height: cameraButtonBar.height
            width: cameraButtonBar.width * 0.125
            icon: "leftarrow.svg"
            visible: capturedFrame.visible && (imageCaptureModel.capturableSelected.length > 1)
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please also include the code that doesn't work

Comment: @Amfasis, The JavaScript itself does work but when the state changes that causes the function to return true instead of false this does not effect the button and only changing the qml property does cause it to re-evaluate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution which works is to use Qt.binding:

```
        Item {    
            id: root
            ...
            Button {
                id: prevImageButton
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 24
                anchors.top: capturedAreaRect.top
                enabled: Qt.binding(images.moreThanOne())
                height: cameraButtonBar.height
                width: cameraButtonBar.width * 0.125
                icon: "leftarrow.svg"
                visible: capturedFrame.visible && (imageCaptureModel.capturableSelected.length > 1)
                ....
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Function return values are not automatically re-evaluated in QML until at least one of the function arguments is updated AND the argument should be a QML object property. I can recommend two approaches:

- You should bind the `prevImageButton` to `moreThanOne` function while the `moreThanOne` accepts a property of its own object (here image) where that property is being changed when the images object is updated

```
    Images{
        id:images
        ....
        property var updateCounter : 0

        function whichEverFunctionThatUpdatesImages(){
            ...
            updateCounter++;
        }
        function moreThanOne(uc){
            // you may want to use it or not
            .... return count>0;
        }
    }

    Button{
       enabled : images.moreThanOne(images.updateCounter)
    }
```

- Define a property inside `Images` which is update by `moreThanOne` and bind it instead

```
Images{
        id:images
        ....
        property var updateCounter : 0
        property var twoOrMore : false

        function whichEverFunctionThatUpdatesImages(){
            ...
            twoOrMore = iCount > 1 ;
        }
    }

    Button{
       enabled : images.twoOrMore
    }
```

I choose the latter option.

**EDIT:**

The following example works quite well on ***btn2*** without using the above methods. But if I use anything other than QML properties like an attribute from a javascript object like what is happening on ***moreThanOne2()*** method, then it stops to work out of the box and those two approaches for re-evaluation will work.

```
 Item {
        id : item
        anchors.fill: parent

        property var aCounter: 0
        property var someObject: ({ counter: 0})

        Button{
            anchors.top: parent.top
            text: 'btn1'
            onClicked: {
                parent.aCounter++
                parent.someObject.counter++
            }
        }

        Button{
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            text: 'btn2'
            enabled: item.moreThanOne1()
        }

        Button{
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.right: parent.right
            text: 'btn3'
            enabled: item.moreThanOne2()
        }


        function moreThanOne1(){
            return aCounter > 1;
        }

        function moreThanOne2(){
            return someObject.counter > 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this approach is exactly how its done at the moment using a QML property to trigger the update.  If the real answer is you can't do it any other way then fair enough.

Comment: @SPlatten, there are other dirty hacks. But actually, this is how it works by design.